# Literal String vs. `String` in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Playing with swift I found this surprising:

```
"123".integerValue // <= returns 123

var x = "123"
x.integerValue     // <= Error: String does not have a member named integerValue
```

Can someone explain?

Comment: It looks like "123".integerValue is bridging it over to NSString.

`var x = "123"; (x as NSString).integerValue // <= returns 123`

Comment: @MalcolmJarvis Or the more verbose: `x.bridgeToObjectiveC().integerValue`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that in the first example the compiler uses the call to `integerValue` as additional information to infer the type (choosing between NSString and a Swift String).

In the second example it probably defaults to a Swift String because it doesn't evaluate multiple lines.

Comment: To add to this, you can explicitly type the variable `var x:NSString = "123"` to resolve the issue

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. Didn't realize things like method calls would factor into inference, but it makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is an example of type inference in action. When you do: `"123".integerValue` the compiler detects that in this case you want to use an `NSString` (which it also does when you use string literals as arguments to objective-c functions.

A similar example is:

```
// x is an Int
let x = 12

// here we tell the compiler that y is a Double explicitly
let y: Double  = 12

// z is a Double because 2.5 is a literal Double and so "12" is also
// parsed as a literal Double
let z = 12 * 2.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.toInt()`

```
var x = "123"

var num: Int = x.toInt()
```

Comment: Yeah I know that. I was just surprised by the result I was seeing.

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```
var x = "123" as NSString
x.integerValue

var x : NSString = "123" // or this as Sulthan suggests
```

it won't show that error.

I think your first example is automatically picking up that you want to use a NSString as NSString only has this .integerValue call.

The second example is probably failing because it's not being told what it is and deciding to use a swift string instead.

Comment: `var x : NSString = "123"` would probably be better